# count number of dictionaries within a dictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary

my questions is about iPhone development.

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to count ONLY the number of dictionaries within a dictionary.

for example, let's say this is my dictionary

Dictionary contains 5 elements:

1. string
2. string
3. NSDictionary
4. NSDictionary
5. NSDictionary

I would like to count only the NSDictionaries... so the return value should be 3.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSSet *dictKeys = [myDict keysOfEntriesPassingTest:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    return [obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]];
}];
NSUInteger numberOfDicts = [dictKeys count];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDictionary* root = ...;

__block NSUInteger count = 0;
[root enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock: ^(id key, id obj, BOOL* stop) {
    if ( [obj isKindOfClass: NSDictionary.class] ) ++ count;
    *stop = NO;
}];
```

Of course

```
NSUInteger count = 0;
for (id obj in root) {
    if ( [obj isKindOfClass: NSDictionary.class] ) ++ count;
}
```

will work as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
__block NSInteger countOfDictionaries = 0;

[dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:(void (^)(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop))block             {
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
          countOfDictionaries++;
    }
}];
```

As shown above, simply enumerate through every object of your dictionary and keep a count of every object that is an "NSDictionary", by testing the class of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your NSDictionary by using NSEnumrator and do the following test :

> if ([myObject class] == [NSDictionary class]) c++;

Comment: Ouch, this is like begging for errors! Especially when dealing with class clusters like `NSDictionary`.